# Задать шаг цикла for

Tags: pascal

Задача: Есть одномерный массив с указанием его длины вручную. Нужно суммировать каждый третий элемент массива!

Пример:

`[20, 132, 43, 325, 26, 1326, 236, 2163, 98, 9] //Сумма: 43 + 1326 + 98 = 1467 (суммируется каждый третий)`

Вот мой код, прошу усовершенствовать:

```
Var arr : array[0..1000000] of Integer;
    num,sum,i : Integer;
    
Begin
  Randomize;
  writeln('Укажите длину массива: ');

  readln(num);
  num := num-1;

  for i:=0 to num do Begin
    arr[i] := random(100)-50;
    sum := sum + arr[i];
    write(arr[i], ' ');
  End;
  writeln('Сумма: ', sum); 
End.
```

...или дать подсказку. Главное условие: без цикла if.

Comment: ну так прочитайте синтаксис цикла for ?

Comment: удалил ответ со `step`. не знаю откуда у меня это в голове. в документации к delphi этого не оказалось. что-то я несколько в недоумении.

Answer (score 0):

в вашем случае

```
for i:=0 to num do Begin
    arr[i] := random(100)-50;
    write(arr[i], ' ');

    if i mod 3 = 2 then begin
        sum := sum + arr[i];
    end;
End;
```

хотя лучше все таки разбить на модули и сначала заполнить весь массив значениями, а затем уже что-то делать с массивом, а не все в одной куче

Если нужен каждый третий и не использоваться if, то должно выглядеть так:

```
// заполняем массив значениями и выводим на экран
for i := 0 to num do Begin
    arr[i] := random(100)-50;
    write(arr[i], ' ');
End;

// выводим каждый третий элемент
for i := 0 to num div 3 do Begin
    sum := sum + arr[3 * i];
End;
```

т.е. мы просто во втором цикле проходим по тройкам значений и берем первое значение из тройки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но главным условием было без цикла if

Comment: @Scourde, тогда использовать `step`, но для этого придется разрывать цикл на два, как я и написал выше, в одном вводить значения, во втором их уже обрабатывать

Comment: Разве `step` в паскале есть? Люди пишут, что `step` в бэйсике только есть

Comment: @Scourde, а... забыл pascal :) Ну тогда используем старый добрый трюк с `index * 3` - посмотрите, я добавил в конце своего поста новый код - никаких `if` там уже нет

Comment: Ну без **if**, так без **if**: `sum := sum + arr[i] * Ord(i mod 3 = 2);`. Только этот хак не на всех компиляторах сработает.